# storing a variable from turtle.onclick(turtle.textinput())

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm trying to program a slidepuzzle game and I've been given several potential files to load. The files need to be loaded from a clickable button within turtle itself. Ive written the following code-

```
def button_click(x,y):
    if (x > 247 and x < 315) and (y > -292 and y < -246): #exit on click exit
        turtle.onclick(quit(1))
    elif (x > 143 and x < 213) and (y > -302 and y < -236): #load on click
          load = turtle.onclick(turtle.textinput('Prompt',"prompt"))
          print(load)
```

The quit button is working when clicked and the load prompt is showing up when the load button is clicked, but when the print(load) variable statement goes off in the terminal it keeps returning "none".

Ideally, load should be returning a valid string file name (entered by the user) that I can use as input into another function to begin loading the parameters of the puzzle. No matter what you type into the prompt box now, it just returns none.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `turtle.onclick(quit(1))` should be `turtle.onclick(lambda x, y: quit(1))` or maybe `turtle.exitonclick()`. Ditto: `turtle.onclick(lambda x, y: print(turtle.textinput('Prompt',"prompt")))`. You're calling these functions immediately and passing their return values to the handler, a common mistake. You want to pass a function reference itself so that turtle can call it on your behalf later. `turtle.onclick()` returns None, it just registers a handler.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

load has now successfully become a variable, I just had to remove the turtle.onclick- now the code looks like this.

```
def button_click(x,y):
if (x > 247 and x < 315) and (y > -292 and y < -246): #exit on click exit
    turtle.onclick(quit(1))
elif (x > 143 and x < 213) and (y > -302 and y < -236): #load on click
    load = turtle.textinput('prompt','prompt')
    print (load)
```